# How to fix manually resized textarea programatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textarea with resize css property. I know how to resize it using javascript by setting *rows*, for e.g.

*document.querySelector('textarea').rows = "10";*

It works perfectly. Now when i resize textarea manually and then try to set rows using function, it wont work as expected.

I have debugged the problem and it is due to height, When we resize textarea manually it adds height to the textarea and when i resize it programattically it doest add any height, and this is causing problem.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Here is example.
Click on below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2O728X99KGS

Click on Run button.

Now click on `Resize Me` button

You can see textarea is resized.

Now resize textarea manually by dragging resize icon.

Finally click on `Resize Me` button, there is no any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `height` to `auto`. Try below code-

```js
function resizeMe(){
document.querySelector('textarea').rows = "10";
document.querySelector('textarea').style.height = "auto";
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>

<button onclick="resizeMe()">Resize Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is inline style attribute. So remove the style attribute before setting the rows

```js
function resizeMe() {
  let elem = document.querySelector('textarea');
  elem.setAttribute("style","");
  elem.rows = "10";
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>

<button onclick="resizeMe()">Resize Me</button>
```